# Way to modify header tag generated by include?

Tags: php, google-analytics, include, google-experiments

I have about 50 pages, each of them contains an include for the header part:

`include './include/header.php';`

and `header.php` contains code such as:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title><?php echo $title; ?></title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
</head>
<body>
```

But now, for about 20 pages I want to conduct Google Experiments, and need to have A/B versions for them.

Google requires that in the original page, I would add an individual block of code for each experiment, right after the `<head>` tag:

```
<head>
//type 1 block of code for page 1 //
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">

<head>
//type 2 block of code for page 2 //
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
```

and so on.

What would be the easiest/smartest way to handle this?

EDIT:

Ok, I think I should edit `header.php` to look like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<?php if  ($experiment==true) { ?>     // New      
[some way to insert block of code ]   // New           
<?php } else { } ?> // New
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title><?php echo $title; ?></title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
</head>
<body>
```

And in every individual page that should have an experiment, I would add this code at top of page:

`$experiment = "big block of code 1"`

But how exactly do I do it?

Comment: a simple if\else block would be fine

Comment: @Dagon I edited my question to come up with something like that, but I'm not sure how to do it exactly.